# Unable to get Mysql 8.0.22 to dump databases using any version of MySql Workbench on MacOs

Tags: macos, mysql-workbench

I have a massive (200 million record) database stored in MySql 8.0.022. I have tried to get MySql Workbench to dump the database to an external SSD, but I keep getting the message "Could not get mysqldump version".

I have scoured all the threads for almost a week, tried all the proposed solutions that have been proposed, and it just will not work.

For some inexplicable reason, every version of Workbench that I install simply fails to connect to the mysqldump executable that is stored in /usr/local/mysql-8.0.22-macos10.15-x86_64/bin.

My data is currently trapped on my MacBook, and I need to make a backup so I can get it onto and AWS server but I am totally stumped. I'm completely self taught, and find MySql incredibly dense and hard to understand, so can anyone please help me out?  Thanks. Ian

Answer (score 0):

MySql Workbench does a pretty good job of logging when there is an issue. You should be able to find out what your specific issue is by **reviewing the workbench log file**.

| OS | Location |
| --- | --- |
| Windows | %AppData%\MySQL\Workbench\log\wb.log |
| macOS | ~username/Library/Application Support/MySQL/Workbench/log/wb.log |
| Linux | ~username/.mysql/workbench/log/wb.log |

You can also locate your log files (all of them) by going to the Workbench menu:

`Help` → `Locate Log Files`

You will likely see an error at the bottom of the file indicating the problem. For example:

```
17:07:07 [ERR][wb_admin_export.py:get_mysqldump_version:126]: Could not parse version number from mysqldump.exe:
file not found
```